# How to force a columnbreak within references section using multicols

Tags: bibliographies, columnbreak

I am creating a poster using the beamerposter section. At the end of the file, I added my bibliography (using natbib) in a multicols environment, to have it on two different columns to gain some space.

However, the columnbreak happens in the middle of an entry. I was wondering if there is a solution to control the column breaking inside the bibliography section.

Edit (code tried):

```
\begin{block}{References}
\begin{tiny}
\setlength{\columnsep}{10pt}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\bibliography{ref}
\end{multicols}
\bibliographystyle{apalike2}
\end{tiny}
\nocite{*}
\end{block}
```

Comment: Welcome, have you tried a simple `\columnbreak`?

Comment: This is indeed what I would like to do. But I don't know where to insert the command in the code, since the bibliography is generated automatically:

    `\begin{block}{References}
      \begin{multicols}{2}
        \bibliography{ref}
       \end{multicols}
       \bibliographystyle{apalike2}
     \end{block}`

Comment: do any of your bib entries require more then 3 lines?  if not, before triggering the bibliography, you can set `\widowpenalty=10000` and `\clubpenalty=10000`.

Comment: Or use `\enlargethispage{-2\baselineskip}` to make the page a bit shorter (and make the page break sooner).

Comment: I used `\patchcmd{\bibsetup}{\interlinepenalty=5000}{\interlinepenalty=10000}{}{}` to prevent pagebreaks within the entries. I'm not sure if it would help against column breaks as well. Could you post a minimal working wxample?

Comment: Less elegantly, if you're done writing your poster and don't need to update the bibliography anymore, you could probably just open the bibliography (`*.bbl`) file and add the `\columnbreak` by hand.

Comment: I tried all your examples, but none of them worked, maybe because of the beamerposter document class.
However, @Roel solution to modify the `*.bbl` file worked for me, even if it is indeed less elegant!